# ～ないかな (Negative Verb Form with Positive Translation)

Tags: grammar, translation, slang

I encountered the following as I was reading chapter 29 of the manga **かぐや様は告らせたい** (images of the section are linked below if it matters). The lines are stated by a very cynical, depressive type character who has a irrational and jealous hatred toward members of sports clubs.

> あぁほんと・・・
>
> 全員　死なねー
>
> かな・・・・

I would have translated this to something like: **Yeah, really...I wonder if they're all not dead..**

Now, I sincerely doubted that that was correct since it didn't make any sense at all so I consulted the fan translation:

> Yeah...
> Maybe...
> They should all just die...

This translation makes more sense to me and I assume it is a valid translation.

**Could someone please explain the grammar (although I'm certain there is some slang involved) that caused 死なねー (死なない presumably) to be given a positive meaning?**

[Japanese panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHq5H.jpg)
[English panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1e5WK.png)

Comment: I found this reference which explains かな in some degree of depth https://www.tofugu.com/japanese/japanese-particle-kana/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This ねー is ない as you've correctly guessed. かな is [usually "I wonder ～"](http://www.jgram.org/pages/viewOne.php?tagE=kana), but (ない)かな often expresses one's *wish*. 全員死なねーかな means "I wish they all die."

> #### [かな](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/43373/meaning/m0u/)
>
> ３ （「ないかな」の形で）**願望**の意を表す。「だれか代わりに行ってくれないかな」「早く夜が明けないかな」

This translates to a positive English sentence because ～ないかな is essentially a rhetorical question like "Why not ～?". You can choose whichever fits better in the context, between "I wish ～" or "I wonder (if) ～". See [this related question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4045/5010), too.

Some more examples:

> - 空を飛べないかな。
> - どこかに1億円落ちてないかな。
> - はやくクリスマスが来ないかな。

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, I discord about the wish.
It's not an resolute wish. It's more like "if possible, it would be great"

There are 2 meanings for this construction ～ないかな, "I think ... not ..." (negative opinion) and "I wonder..." (desire)
It also depends on the construction before:

- 私、空を飛べないかな
  I wonder if I can fly
- 私は、空は飛べないかな
  I think I can't fly