# Can someone please explain to me the grammar in the sentence このデータをうまく活用して、何かできないかな。

Tags: grammar, modality

> このデータをうまく活用して、何かできないかな。

This sentence is from Wanikani, and it's translated as "I don’t know if I can put this data to good use." I understand the first part of the sentence, but I don't know why 何かできないかな is translated, or has the meaning of "I don't know." Is it a set phrase?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/50330/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4045/9831

Answer (score 3):

かな is added to add some kind of uncertainty to the sentence, to show that you are unsure. It is often a way of asking someone else for confirmation.

To make a more literal translation I would thus say:

> I wonder if something can't be done, to put this data to good use